# Gulp image resize failing

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I have a `gulpfile.js` which has one function to resize images and one to minify them.

The minification works and is all good, however, the resize is throwing an undefined error and I can't figure out what is causing it.

All I want is to loop the images in `images/` and run them through the `gulp-image-resize` function call in the `resize` task and have it do the same but also minify it in the `resizeMinify` task, but the package is failing...

What is it that I am missing here?

```js
//requirements
var gulp = require('gulp');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
var imageResize = require('gulp-image-resize');

//task declarations
gulp.task('imagemin', function() {
  return gulp
    .src('images/**.*')
    .pipe(imagemin({
      progressive: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images'))
});

gulp.task('imageresize', function() {
  return gulp
    .src('images/**.*')
    .pipe(imageResize({
      width: 800,
      height: 600
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images'));
});

gulp.task('resizeMinify', function() {
  return gulp
    .src('images/**.*')
    .pipe(imageResize({
      width: 800,
      height: 600
    }))
    .pipe(imagemin({
      progressive: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images'));
});

//task call setups
gulp.task('resize', ['imageresize']);
gulp.task('minify', ['imagemin']);
gulp.task('default', ['resizeMinify']);
```

Cheers,
SD

Comment: Does it work if you run `gulp resize` alone?

Comment: Nope, only `gulp minify` is working.

Comment: Or you can debug with node-inspector. AFAIK gulp does not have verbose mode like `grunt --verbose`. http://www.greg5green.com/blog/debugging-gulp-js-tasks/

Comment: Already tried, nothing of value showing though. Perhaps you could try the code and see too, but yeah, its just the plugin throwing an undefined error.

Comment: You do have ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick installed right? and those libraries can be access from terminal right?